# Vlookup in SQL query based on each column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare table 1 value into table 2 but not only one column but into multiple columns and include the date as well.

Table 1

```
----+-----------+
| Id | date      |
| 1  | 4/15/2020 |
| 2  | 4/16/2020 |
| 3  | 4/17/2020 |
| 4  | 4/18/2020 |
| 5  | 4/19/2020 |
| 6  | 4/20/2020 |
| 7  | 4/21/2020 |
| 8  | 4/22/2020 |
| 9  | 4/23/2020 |
| 10 | 4/24/2020 |
| 11 | 4/25/2020 |
| 12 | 4/26/2020 |
| 13 | 4/27/2020 |
| 14 | 4/28/2020 |
| 15 | 4/29/2020 |
| 16 | 4/30/2020 |
| 17 | 5/1/2020  |
| 18 | 5/2/2020  |
| 19 | 5/3/2020  |
| 20 | 5/4/2020  |
+----+-----------+
```

Table 2

```
+-------+------+-------+--------+------+-------+
| Batch | call | Zone  | Batch2 | call | zone  |
| 1     | A    | South | 100    | B    | North |
| 15    | A    | South | 102    | B    | North |
| 22    | A    | South | 105    | B    | North |
| 30    | A    | South | 605    | B    | North |
| 2     | A    | South | 44     | B    | North |
| 8     | A    | South | 78     | B    | North |
| 75    | A    | South | 1      | B    | North |
| 80    | A    | South | 2      | B    | North |
| 6     | A    | South | 3      | B    | North |
| 4     | A    | South | 78     | B    | North |
| 8     | A    | South | 6      | B    | North |
| 45    | A    | South | 9      | B    | North |
| 60    | A    | South | 78     | B    | North |
| 78    | A    | South | 9      | B    | North |
| 34    | A    | South | 10     | B    | North |
| 80    | A    | South | 11     | B    | North |
| 46    | A    | South | 12     | B    | North |
| 77    | A    | South | 789    | B    | North |
| 95    | A    | South | 456    | B    | North |
| 400   | A    | South | 658    | B    | North |
+-------+------+-------+--------+------+-------+
```

Result:

```
+-------+------+-----------+------+-------+--------+------+-------+------+-------+
| Batch | id   | date      | call | Zone  | Batch2 | id   | date  | call | zone  |
| 1     | 1    | 4/15/2020 | A    | South | 100    | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
| 15    | 15   | 4/29/2020 | A    | South | 102    | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
| 22    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 105    | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
| 30    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 605    | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
| 2     | 2    | 4/16/2020 | A    | South | 44     | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
| 8     | 8    | 4/22/2020 | A    | South | 78     | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
| 75    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 1      | 1    | 43936 | B    | North |
| 80    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 2      | 2    | 43937 | B    | North |
| 6     | 6    | 4/20/2020 | A    | South | 3      | 3    | 43938 | B    | North |
| 4     | 4    | 4/18/2020 | A    | South | 78     | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
| 8     | 8    | 4/22/2020 | A    | South | 6      | 6    | 43941 | B    | North |
| 45    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 9      | 9    | 43944 | B    | North |
| 60    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 78     | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
| 78    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 9      | 9    | 43944 | B    | North |
| 34    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 10     | 10   | 43945 | B    | North |
| 80    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 11     | 11   | 43946 | B    | North |
| 46    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 12     | 12   | 43947 | B    | North |
| 77    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 789    | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
| 95    | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 456    | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
| 400   | #N/A | #N/A      | A    | South | 658    | #N/A | #N/A  | B    | North |
+-------+------+-----------+------+-------+--------+------+-------+------+-------+
```

Query:

```
select batch,
    (case when batch=id then id else null end ) id,
    (case when batch=id then date else null end) date,
    call,
    zone,
    batch2,
    (case when batch2=id then id else null end ) id1,
    (case when batch2=id then date else null end) date1,
    call,
    zone
table1 x
left join table2 y on x.id=y.batch and x.id=y.batch2
```

Comment: So what is your question? Doesn't your query work as-intended?

Comment: I assume the missing `from` before `table1` is just a typo?

Comment: nope, it is working for only one column( batch) not for both.

Comment: @SteveRichard: please show us the result that you actually expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to `JOIN` table2 to table1 twice, once to get the first batch's date, and once to get the second:

```
select y.batch1,
    (case when y.batch1=x1.id then x1.id else null end ) id1,
    (case when y.batch1=x1.id then x1.date else null end) date1,
    call1,
    zone1,
    y.batch2,
    (case when y.batch2=x2.id then x2.id else null end ) id2,
    (case when y.batch2=x2.id then x2.date else null end) date2,
    call2,
    zone2
from table2 y
left join table1 x1 on x1.id=y.batch1
left join table1 x2 on x2.id=y.batch2
```

Output is too long to paste here but there's a [demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45cd59/4).

Note that I had to change some column names since you have duplicates in table2.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your solution